# How to convert UIImage to JSON file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, json, uiimage

I have been using **NSJSONSerialization** class for converting fields of my object to JSON. Sadly only **NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull** types are supported.

As my object has one additional field, that is **UIImage**, I am at loss as to how to deal with it. I am sure many people have encountered this common problem, so what is best method to approach this?

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what you want to accomplish.
'cause JSON is not the utmost best format for images

Comment: I have a NSManagedObject that has many fields. I want send that data to web server, so i pack it into json file and send it to server. Also server can send me back some data also in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encode `UIImage` data by base64, and add it to json object.
To get data from UIImage, you can use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

The code like this,

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *base64encodedStr = base64encode(imageData);
[dict setObject:base64encodedStr forKey:@"myImage"];
//then covert dict to json object.
```

To restore `UIImage` data, just parse json object and decode the data by base64.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: There is no base64encode function, did you write it yourself?

Comment: @MegaManX Yes, you need to write base64 function by your self.

Comment: Oh, cra* thats the hardest part :-(, it's 90% of solution

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your images data to a string and then write that string.

```
NSData *imageData = UIPNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//I don't know how to use NSJSONSerialization
//[NSJSONSerialization serializeString:imageString];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *base64encodedStr = [imageData base64Encoding];
```